# How can implent SSO (Single Sign On) Authentication to my Blazor server side app? I have built the app with the setting "Windows Authentication"

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor server side app currently working with Windows Authentication. Due to the company regulations I have been asked for implementing single sign on. Our company supports just SAML or Open ID Connect protocols for single sign on.

As I a have no experience on it I want to learn How I can implement SSO in the easiest way? Is it a problem that I have chooesen the "Windows Authentication" at the start of generating the application? I hope that I don't have to generate my app new.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on the same issue and have successfully authenticated using Blazor Server App and Microsoft.Identity. If you started a Visual Studio project using the Blazor Server App template, choose Microsoft.Identity rather than Windows authentication methods. It will include all the necessary packages and scaffold out the base.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. But in this case do I have to create the project from beginning? Or can I swich anywhere from Windows Authentication to Microsoft.Identity?

Comment: Depending on versioning, I believe you will find that information in the `Program.cs` file. I have not done this before, but a quick search should get you started. This Reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/Blazor/comments/17g9uq0/how_do_i_switch_from_windows_authentication_to/?rdt=64978 might be a good place to start. Hope it helps.